# Updating context value in react-admin causes a router history warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm using context to store a global piece of information which is updated when navigating around the web app from a Link component. For some reason, when I update the context data, I get a "Warning: You cannot change <Router history>" in the console. My data has no history object in it, just a value and a function to update. What could cause this?

Here is my setup:

```
const AppContext = createContext({
    appData: {},
    setAppData: () => {},
});

const App = () => {

  const [appData, setAppData] = useState({
    foo: null,
  });

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[appData, setAppData]}>
        <Admin title="My Admin App">
          <Resource name="foo" show={ShowFoo} />
        </Admin>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

My menu has nav links using this component:

```
export const MyMenuLink = ({ primaryText, to, leftIcon, sidebarIsOpen, onMenuClick, dense, foo }) => {
    
    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        const newAppData = {
            ...appData,
            foo: foo,
        };
        setAppData(newAppData);    
    };

    return (
        <Link to={to} onClick={clickHandler}>                            
            <Typography variant="inherit">{primaryText}</Typography>            
        </Link>
    );
};
```

So when I click on that link, I get the router history warning, but if I remove the setAppData() call in clickHandler, it disappears.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely your `<Router>` component is re-rendered with a new 'history' prop. You haven't shared that piece of code, I guess it sits somewhere below `AppContext.provider` [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148365/react-router-keeps-giving-me-a-warning-you-cannot-change-router-routes) should be helpfull. You can lift the initialisation of the 'history'  you're passing into the router to some place outside the render/component.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with a Router component or history object since I leave that to be handled by react-admin. Pretty much everything between AppContext.Provider is shown (except a few more resource elements) but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Warning: You cannot change `<Router history>`

This is a message coming from [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main). React router supports different history-objects, but usually you would connect to a `BrowserHistory` and allow the browsers to handle and propagate route changes to the router.
IE pressing the browsers forward/backward buttons will trigger a re-render, not a total page refresh.

## React-admin

React-router is also used by React-Admin.
You can pass along a history into the root `<Admin />` component.
If you don't set a history, react-admin will create one for you.

Passing in a history is as simple as:

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const App = ()=>{
return (<Admin
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        history={history}
      />)
}
```

## Rerenders

React-router doesn't want the history reference to change.
If you attempt to change it, you'll see the warning pop up.
React will re-render child components when something in the parent changes.
In your case, the context will re-render their children whenever a new value is received in the provider. (basically when calling `setAppData`)
This will trigger a rerender on your `<Admin>` component.
Since we didn't pass in a history, a new one is created and passed to the router. [probably here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/175fa190a9aca6b440c969ae28f198b3dea5ac94/packages/ra-core/src/routing/AdminRouter.tsx#LL44C12-L44C12)
You will then see the warning from react router.

Passing in your own router would solve that.

##### sandbox

You can try it in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-swirles-ntj9g4).
If you comment out the the history prop, you will receive warnings again.
There's a link on the dashboard to trigger the re-render.

Comment: Thank you so much for not just answering but providing a clear and concise summary of the "why". Great response!